How to merge the following 2 files using python or bash?
The first file (tab-delimited) is
a       1       2       3
b       6       7       8
c       9       0       9

The second file (tab-delimited) is
a_rna_1 r       r       x
a_rna_2 q       q       d
a_rna_3 c       c       c
b_rna_1 e       e       e
c_rna_1 a       a       g

How can we merge these 2 files so that we get the following file?
a       1       2       3      a_rna_1 r       r       x
a       1       2       3      a_rna_2 q       q       d
a       1       2       3      a_rna_3 c       c       c
b       6       7       8      b_rna_1 e       e       e
c       9       0       9      c_rna_1 a       a       g

Is there a way that we can do this automatically?

wha't the logic on the sequences? what is the problem?

just the first character of each row?

I have edited the question here. Sorry for the confusion. The spacing got mixed up.

yes. just the first character of each row.

I python , open both files, loop over the first , read the first character , then, in the same loop, loop over the second file and read the first character, if the 2 characters are equal use the operator + to append the strings and write the line in a new file

This is the sort of thing the join command was designed to do; it's basically a SQL JOIN that operates on text files rather than tables in an RDBMS. But it won't quite work out of the box on these files, because you don't have fields that exactly match; an a in one file matches something starting with a_rna_... in the other. My solution is to break off the part of the second key that matches the first and prepend it as a new column to the front of the second file; after that, join can do the job.
Here's a command that should do the trick:
join <(sort file1.tsv) <(sed 's/^\([^_]*\)_/\1\t&/' file2.tsv | sort)

Explanation:
The <(...) syntax is process substitution. You can put any command that generates output inside the parentheses, and pass the whole thing as an argument to a program expecting the name of a file to read; the program will read the output of the command instead.  This lets us do some prep work on the files before feeding them to join, without having to create temporary files to hold the prepared versions.
Both files have to be sorted by their keys for join to be able to match them up. You can always sort the final result differently; they just have to be consistent with each other for the join operation. The first file is otherwise fine as-is, so the sort is the only thing we do in the process sub.
For the second file, we use sed to read off the part of the first column before the underscore and prepend it as a new tab-delimited column at the front of the line.
Here's a breakdown of the sed s/ regex / replacement /
expression:
v-- at the start of the line
  v----------v remember what matches

^ \( [^_] * \) _

          ^--- any number of repetitions of
     ^--^ any character that's not an underscore
               ^--- followed by an underscore

And replace it with:
v--- just the stuff matched by the bit within \(...\)

   v--- followed by a tab 

\1 \t &

      ^--- followed by whatever matched the whole thing 
       

So after the sed, this line:
a_rna_1 r       r       x       

Turns into this:
a       a_rna_1 r       r       x

We pipe the output of sed to sort, and now we're ready to join.
The join combines the fields of the two files wherever the join columns (the first one, by default) match up. And it only prints one copy of the join column, so the output looks just like you want it to:
a       1       2       3       a_rna_1 r       r       x
a       1       2       3       a_rna_2 q       q       d
a       1       2       3       a_rna_3 c       c       c
b       6       7       8       b_rna_1 e       e       e
c       9       0       9       c_rna_1 a       a       g


Thank you Mark for your clear explanation. Your help is much appreciated!

Another approach, using paste instead of join: paste <(sed -f <(sed -n '$! { N;/^\([^_]*\)_.*\n\1/{ h;s|^\([^_]*\)_.*|/^\1/p|p;;g;};D }' file-b.txt) file-a.txt) file-b.txt

A Python solution is trivial:
with open("file1.txt") as f1, open("file2.txt") as f2, open("file3.txt", "w") as f3:
    i2 = 0
    l2 = f2.readlines()
    for l1 in map(str.strip, f1):
        t1, *_ = l1.split()
        while i2 < len(l2) and l2[i2].startswith(t1):
            f3.write(l1+l2[i2])
            i2 += 1


I wouldn't normally answer a question that doesn't contain any attempt by the OP to solve the problem themselves, but since this one has multiple answers already ... using any awk:
$ awk -F'[_\t]' -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} {print a[$1], $0}' file1 file2
a       1       2       3       a_rna_1 r       r       x
a       1       2       3       a_rna_2 q       q       d
a       1       2       3       a_rna_3 c       c       c
b       6       7       8       b_rna_1 e       e       e
c       9       0       9       c_rna_1 a       a       g

